# Mean of an exponential of indicator function

Tags: probability, expectation, means

Small question that has been in my head for several days.

$$ E[\exp(iu1_{Z\succeq t})] = \exp(iu)P(Z\succeq  t)$$

Is that statement true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. $Ee^{iuI_{\{Z\geq t\}}}=e^{iu}P\{Z\geq t\}+P\{Z<t\}$. Note that $e^{iuI_{\{Z\geq t\}}}=1$ on the event $\{Z<t\}$. You have to take this part alos into account.